# Someone help me to convert from handwrited array to natural array

Tags: javascript

I have to convert that handwrited array, to natural array.

```js
var json = "[";
  if(result.length > 0) {
    json += `{ "${result[0].ped_id}": { "id": ${result[0].id}, "ocupped": ${result[0].ocupped} } }`;
  }
json += "]";
```

The array should looking like that: `[ { '1': { id: 1, ocupped: 0 } } ]`, someone have an idea what i can do?

Comment: Do you mean JSON.parse()?

Comment: @danh The json is hand writed, so it won't work with JSON parse (if there are more than one elements)

Comment: If it won't work with JSON.parse then it's not JSON.

Comment: Maybe the OP is aiming to implement a parse without using parse (as an exercise?)?

Comment: Post what `result` looks like originally (*"handwritten"*).

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you should create the object first, then JSON.stringify it.

```js
let result = [{
  ped_id: 101,
  occuped: "something"
}]
let json = [];
if (result.length > 0) {
  json.push({
    [result[0].ped_id]: {
      id: result[0].ped_id.toString(),
      ocupped: result[0].ocupped
    }
  })
}
json = JSON.stringify(json)
console.log(json)
```